# Should we build out AI topics and tags?

Tags: discussion

Given that [the Area 51 StackExchange site for Artificial Intelligence got shut down](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6607/artificial-intelligence), should we make an attempt to appropriate those questions into robotics?

E.g. [this question about POMDPs](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/7644/350)

By "build out", I mean set up some tags for robotics-related AI topics.

Answer (score 1):

There is little point in adding tags before questions which need those tags are created. Tags are intended to provide meta data about questions rather that try to encourage questions about a given tag.

Having said that, if you find questions which could be improved with better tagging, and those tags lead to tag wiki descriptions which make those tags more visible, then that would improve the site for everyone.

Comment: That's true, but on some level having those tags defined indicates that such questions are relevant to this stackexchange site. Are they relevant? Should we welcome and/or encourage them?

Comment: "Build it and they will come" doesn't really work on Stack Exchange, "welcome them if they come" is much more likely to work. I have no problem welcoming AI questions, as long as they are at least tangentially relevant to robotics. More abstract questions about artificial intelligence might be better off on [Cognitive Sciences](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence) though.

Answer (score 0):

Beta Q&A site for AI launched, please join:

- https://ai.stackexchange.com/ ([Visit](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93481/artificial-intelligence))

Comment: It says that the site is in private beta for "at least 12 more days".  What do I do with that?